# Need help in tunning Sql table max date logic

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, query-performance

We have a scenario as mentioned below and need inputs for best logic.
Database is sql server 2012.

I have a table abc with columns 'a' , 'b' , 'c' and a date field 'd'.
if table abc has 10 records with different dates, which is the best optimized way 
to have column 'a' , 'b' , 'c' along with 'd' 
where 'd' is just the max date for entire record set.

e.g. if below is table abc data,

```
a   b   c   d
a1  b1  c1  01-02-2017
a2  b2  c2  02-02-2017
a3  b3  c3  10-02-2017
a4  b4  c4  04-02-2017

what we need is,

a   b   c   d
a1  b1  c1  10-02-2017
a2  b2  c2  10-02-2017
a3  b3  c3  10-02-2017
a4  b4  c4  10-02-2017
```

here we need to replicate the max date across all records.

Things we tried so far.

Option 1. `Select a , b, c, (Select max(d) from abc) d from abc`

Option 2.

```
Select a , b, c, max.max_D from abc
            join (Select max(d) max_D from abc) max on 1=1
```

Note: this is just e.g. our actual requirement is same but we have more than 10 joins and data in table is huge.

Please suggest.

Comment: i think it's so hard to give you a solution if you are not sure your given data..

Answer (score 0):

Your both solutions access table twice..Since you are using 2012,i would suggest using a windows function to deal with this

```
Select a , b, c, 
max(d)over (order by d desc) as maxx
from abc
```

For this query to perform optimally, you will need below index

```
create index nci on table(d)
include(a,b,c)
```

Comment: @TheGameiswarCan you please Explain how that Covering index will be executed

Comment: For this window function,the index should be  of form , `POC` which means Partioning and order by columns should be  key columns and rest should be included

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have optimized insert,
you can simply use the MAX function in your SELECT queries.

If you wish to have optimized select,
you can use a computed column (which will reduce INSERT/UPDATE performance).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @MaxDate datetime

Select @MaxDate=max(d) from table1

select a,b,c @MaxDate d from table1
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.